# Getting TypeError: validatetoken is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, jwt

I'm using the below to validate some data before its sent elsewhere, I have a function validate that checks if two other functions (validatetoken & validate_added_mods)return true before validate returns true itself.

My problem is that i get a typeerror when the validate function attempts to call the other functions saying they're in fact not functions, i'm quite new to JS so I may have some glaringly obvious blind spots! Thanks in advance

```
'use strict';
const config = require('./config');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const {body, validationResult} = require('express-validator');
const jwt_decode = require('jwt-decode');
const e = require('express');

class validator{
    constructor(
    token,
    email,
    addedmodtoken,
    current_modules,
    removed_mod_codes
    ){
        this.token = token;
        this.email = email;
        this.addedmodtoken = addedmodtoken;
        this.current_modules = current_modules;  
        this.removed_mod_codes = removed_mod_codes;
    }

    validate(validatetoken, validate_added_mods,token,email) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            try {
                if(validatetoken(token, email) && validate_added_mods(addedmodtoken, email)){
                    resolve(true)

              } else {
                reject;
              };
          } catch(e) {
            reject(e);
          }
        });
    }

    validatetoken(token, email) {
        var decoded = jwt_decode(token);
        var jwtemail = decoded.id;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            try {
                if (email === jwtemail){
                    console.log("Validated token! ");
                    resolve(true);
                } else {
                reject;
              };
          } catch(e) {
            reject(e);
          }
        });
    }
 
    validate_added_mods(addedmodtoken, email) {
        var decoded = jwt_decode(addedmodtoken);
        var jwtemail = decoded.id;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            try {
                if(jwtemail === email){
                    console.log("Validated added modules! ");
                    resolve(true);
                        
                } else {
                reject;
              };
          } catch(e) {
            reject(e);
          }
        });
    }
}

module.exports = validator;
```

Comment: You're not necessarily calling your `validatetoken` function as it's actually the value of whatever is passed in to `validatetoken` parameter of `validate` function. Same with `validate_added_mods`

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling validate()?

Your validate() function takes four arguments: validatetoken, validate_added_mods, token, and email.

When you call validate, you must pass a function as the first argument, since you are using this argument as a function a few lines later.

If you were intending to use the function called validatetoken that you defined a few lines later, then you probably want to remove validatetoken from the list of arguments that validate() accepts.

Remember that symbols with the same names are not necessarily the same symbols. The scope must be the same as well.

(variable and function names are symbols)